# log4j properties files based on leiningen test metadata?

Tags: testing, logging, clojure, log4j, leiningen

How can I use different log4j properties files based on leiningen test metadata? I have functions that have debug logging output to a file. Often, there is a lot of data being written to this debug log file, slowing down the function. Normal runs of the application will not have debug file writing, so I want to benchmark the normal running of the function without that file writing. For benchmarking, I am using criterium. Let's assume that the metadata for benchmarking `deftest` defitions is `:benchmark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with doing this based on test metadata is that all tests are run in a single JVM instance, and modifying the Log4j configuration on the fly within a JVM is not exactly easy. Instead, I would set up profiles in your `project.clj` to disable the `:benchmark` tests by default, and set up a separate profile for running benchmarks. Assuming that you have your `:resource-paths` set up to include a debug-level `log4j.properties` file, your benchmark profile could then set up the classpath or system profiles as appropriate to use a different file. For example:

```
(defproject myproject
  ...
  :test-selectors {:default (complement :benchmark)}
  :profiles {
    :benchmark {
      :test-selectors {:default :benchmark}
      :jvm-opts ["-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-benchmark.properties"]
    }
  })
```

You could then run the benchmarks with:

```
 > lein with-profile +benchmark test
```

Comment: Hm. I already have a log4j.properties file set up in a resources/shared folder. How would I integrate that with what you're suggesting? `:resource-paths ["resources/shared"]` Move to jvm-opts in both situations? Or create a resources/benchmark folder that could override? If the folder strategy worked, I think that would be best, since it could apply to other things than just log4j.properties. What do you think?

Comment: You don't strictly need to use jvm-opts to use log4j.properties in the default case, though it can't hurt. Creating a separate resources/benchmark folder could work nicely, as long as it gets placed in front of your default resources/shared on the effective classpath.